# RealityKit Custom ARAnchor not syncing across devices

Tags: swift, networking, arkit, realitykit, nssecurecoding

I'm using Apple's custom ARAnchor in a `config.isCollaborationEnabled = true` environment.

When I call the following on DeviceA:

```
let boardAnchor = BoardAnchor(transform: last.worldTransform, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 11))
arView.session.add(anchor: boardAnchor)
```

I can see the delegate `func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor])` get called with the BoardAnchor on DeviceA.

However, DeviceB does not receive such a delegate call.

If however I add a non-subclassed ARAnchor on DeviceA, I can see the delegate called on DeviceB.

```
let namedAnchor = ARAnchor(name: "test", transform: last.worldTransform)
arView.session.add(anchor: namedAnchor)
```

So I'm really confused as to why the subclass doesn't work...any ideas?

```
class BoardAnchor: ARAnchor {
let size: CGSize

init(transform: float4x4, size: CGSize) {
    self.size = size
    super.init(name: "Board", transform: transform)
}

override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
    return true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.size = aDecoder.decodeCGSize(forKey: "size")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

// this is guaranteed to be called with something of the same class
required init(anchor: ARAnchor) {
    let other = anchor as! BoardAnchor
    self.size = other.size
    super.init(anchor: other)
}

override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    super.encode(with: aCoder)
    aCoder.encode(size, forKey: "size")
}
}
```

Delegate

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    
    for anchor in anchors {
        DLog("didAdd anchor: \(anchor)")
      
      if anchor.name == "test" {
        // Non-sublcass ARAnchor ok
      }
      
      if let board = anchor as? BoardAnchor {
        // Never called
      }

    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this line from the **Building Collaborative AR Experiences** session (WWDC 2019) might explain the issue you're facing;

> Last, only the user created ARAnchors are shared. That excludes all
> the subclass ARAnchors, including ARImageAnchor, ARPlaneAnchor, and
> ARObjectAnchor. That also excludes the user subclass ARAnchor which
> were used to attach user data within Map Save and Load.

The session seems to go on to indicate that in lieu of using a sublcassed ARAnchor, you can define your own Entity component and conform your Entity to that protocol, hereby allowing you to negate having to use a subclassed ARAnchor and allowing the component, which would synchronize across the session, to perform a similar task.  However, if you are not using RealityKit, and are, instead, using SceneKit or SpriteKit, you will likely need to determine a different methodology, such as avoiding subclassing ARAnchor and move your logic in `BoardAnchor` somewhere else.

Comment: I've watched the clip from 11minutes in the video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/610/?time=752 multiple times, but I still don't understand how I can attach data to the aranchor :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think that other than simply noting the `config.isCollaborationEnabled = true`, you need to manually handle the data sent out and the connectivity and other peers.

In addition, there is a different delegate method to get the collaborated anchors, if I remember correctly.

Please note the following:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_collaborative_session

There is a sample project there that will probably answer most of your questions..

Comment: Unfortunately that sample project doesn't use a sub-classed ARAnchor